# Issues with generating the following block matrix using horizontal stacking and vertical stacking

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to generate the following block matrix consisting of submatrices `A` and `B`, and `N` is a positive integer. So far, my code is as follows:

```
C_lower = B
for j in range(0,N):
    for i in range(0,N-j):
        col = np.linalg.matrix_power(A,i) @ B
        C = np.hstack(np.vstack((C_lower,col)))
```

[image]

However, it seems like my code is not working because the loop continues forever. Any suggestions?

Similarly, I'm also having issues with constructing the following block diagonal matrices:
[image]

I tried using `block_diag` from `scipy`, but there is no way I can repeat `Q` as many times as `N` is equal to (i.e., N = 50 in my case). I had to do `block_diag(Q,Q,Q,Q,Q,Q,Q.......)` in order to get the block diagonal matrix I want.

Comment: Test with a small N.  For loops may take long but they don't run for ever.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer to your first question. There are a number of issues in your code. This is a better way of achieving what you want:

```
C = np.zeros((N, N, A.shape[0], B.shape[1]))
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i + 1):
        C[i, j] = np.linalg.matrix_power(A, i - j) @ B
```

Similarly for your second question:

```
Q_ = np.zeros((N, N, *Q.shape))
for i in range(N):
    Q_[i, i] = Q
```

Comment: thank you! What does the `*` represent in `np.zeros((N, N, *Q.shape))` ?

Comment: I'm actually having some issues again with performing matrix-matrix multiplications on these block matrices : 
```H = C_block.T @ Q_block @ C_block + R_block

F = C_block.T @ Q_block @ C_block```. 
I'm getting an error saying there's a dimension mismatch.

Comment: @RandyChen You're welcome! The `*` unpacks the `Q.shape` tuple, i.e. it is equivalent to writing `np.zeros((N, N, Q.shape[0], Q.shape[1]))`. As for your shape mismatch error, it is hard to know why this is happening from what you wrote. Try posting a new question with clear explanation.

Comment: I just edited my post!

Comment: @RandyChen Changing the entire question is not a good practice. It is confusing for the people who visit this page in the future. Please return this question to what is was and post a new question.